# whose permission is required while sending transaction and how can we give that permission

Tags: transactions, deferred-transactions

I have two accounts viz. account1 and account2. I set my contract using account2. Now, I am sending 0.1100 EOS from account2 to account1 as a deferred transaction. I am using the following function which invokes a function `transfer`.

```
      void second::send(account_name from , account_name to ,asset  quantity,string  memo,uint64_t delay) {
            eosio::transaction t{};

            t.actions.emplace_back(
                eosio::permission_level(from, N(active)),
                account1,
                N(transfer),
                std::make_tuple(from,to,quantity,memo)
            );
            t.delay_sec = delay;
            t.send(N(memo), from);
        }
```

I am passing from ,to,quantity and memo to the action `send`. If I hard code the value of account1, it works and if I set it to some other account it gives the permission exception. 

So, now I am confused how to set the correct permissions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure in your code what's `account1` as it's not defined anywhere. Did you mean `N(account1)`? Also, what does `account1::transfer()` look like? Are you trying to transfer EOS tokens? You should probably be using `eosio.token` as the account to which you send the action then.

Here's an example of a contract that manages the transfer of tokens

```
#include <string>
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>

using std::string;
using std::make_tuple;
using eosio::action;
using eosio::contract;
using eosio::permission_level;
using eosio::asset;

class passtokens : public contract {
  public:
      passtokens (account_name account) : contract(account) {}

      void sendtokens(account_name from, account_name to, asset amount, string memo) { 
          action(
            permission_level{from, N(active)},
            N(eosio.token),
            N(transfer),
            make_tuple(from, to, amount, memo)
          ).send();
      }
};

EOSIO_ABI( passtokens, (sendtokens) )
```

Give permission to the account that uploaded the contract above to use your `active` authority under their `eosio.code` authority:

```
$ cleos set account permission <your-account> active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "<your-key>","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"passtokens","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p <your-account>
```

then send a transaction:

```
$ cleos push action passtokens sendtokens '["<your-account>", "<account-you-want-to-send-tokens-to>", "50.0000 EOS", "memo message"]' -p <your-account>
```

Comment: we have to give permission to the account with which we created our contract right  ?

Comment: yup. in my example above that's `passtokens` as it assumes a `$ cleos set contract passtokens passtokens/`

Comment: What does active authority provide us , Does we set the contract with the same account with which we set active authority under their eosio.code..