# How to transfer/deposit tokens on Front end Dapp with Scatter?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, transactions, eosjs, eosio.token

I am working on an EOS frontend Dapp with Scatter on local chain. I am getting a problem with transfer/deposit tokens from one account to another. After logging into scatter with "test1" and trying to transfer tokens from "test1" to "test2", I get the following error:

```
api error => undefined http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/push_transaction {"compression":"none","transaction":{"expiration":"2018-10-28T14:10:39","ref_block_num":22565,"ref_block_prefix":7727111,"net_usage_words":0,"max_cpu_usage_ms":0,"delay_sec":0,"context_free_actions":[],"actions":[{"account":"test2","name":"transfer","authorization":[{"actor":"test1","permission":"active"}],"data":"000000008090b1ca000000000091b1ca102700000000000004454f5300000000016d"}],"transaction_extensions":[]},"signatures":["SIG_K1_Kdrrfnn48GXVbBykes1WZGmwcb58Y4iLok3kAHbLANnjafJRqFCH5tpGy6Dt4SXwyWeFUaB8yaKa7Ud27v23nvaEJ3JxX9"]}

Error: {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":3050003,"name":"eosio_assert_message_exception","what":"eosio_assert_message assertion failure"
```

Please help me to solve this. It would be great if anyone provided the code!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue not come from setting scatter because it shows the error from smart contract that mean the action already executed. So it is either from your token's smart contract or your action. So please provide more detail your command action then i can help.

TO make sure, please check your command action with cleos

Comment: I am using the eosio.token contract's transfer function in my smart contract. I don't know this is the right way or not to write the transfer function. So if you have any other idea then please suggest. I think you are right, there is no issue from scatter because it's fetching the identity.

Comment: I need more information to help you. What data you put in your transaction? Which network you are using mainnet or testnet or localnet? Have you try with cleos, does it work?

Comment: I got reference from this link: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/how-to-send-eos-based-tokens-from-one-account-to-another?rq=1  so that you will get an idea what i am trying to say. I am using localnet and just call the transfer function by the identity of scatter. I tried on terminal with command:  cleos push action test2 transfer '[ "test1", "test2", "1.0000 EOS", "m" ]' -p test1@active  , i get the following error :  982634ms thread-0   wasm_interface.cpp:929        eosio_assert  ] message: unable to find key 
982731ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:405  handle_exception ]

Comment: FC Exception encountered while processing chain.push_transaction  982731ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:406           handle_exception     ] Exception Details: 3050003 eosio_assert_message_exception: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
assertion failure with message: unable to find key
    {"s":"unable to find key"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:930 eosio_assert
    {"_pending_console_output.str()":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:62 exec_one

Comment: Have you create EOS token for your local network? If not please use following link https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/token-tutorial

Comment: Yes i have done it. Let me check you the command -                                                                                     
cleos get table eosio.token test1 accounts                                           {
  "rows": [{
      "balance": "99.0000 EOS"
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}

Comment: There is a common issue for local network, have you change system token from "SYS" to "EOS"?  Please modify this file eos/eosio_build.sh from CORE_SYMBOL_NAME="SYS" to CORE_SYMBOL_NAME="EOS", then rebuild again.

Comment: I haven't changed the CORE_SYMBOL_NAME instead i created new symbol "SYS" and tried it but same error generated.

Comment: But i saw as above, your command used EOS symbol. as i remember, this issue related symbol name, maybe you didn't create it, or it different symbol in your code. it you still not solve this, inbox private message

Comment: I tried both symbols (EOS or SYS) with this command and it worked smoothly,                                                                     
 cleos push action eosio.token transfer '[ "test1", "test2", "1.0000 EOS", "m" ]' -p test1@active , so i think there may not be an issue with symbol.

Comment: add my telegam quocle 108

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a transaction on the blockchain which is running on `http://127.0.0.1:8888`. Look at this API endpoint in your error, `http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/push_transaction`.
That means either you have to configure this network in scatter or you have to push the transaction on that blockchain server which is configured in `Networks` tab in `Settings`.

HTH.

Comment: I have already configured this network in scatter. The other functions in smart contracts are working fine but having problem with transfer function only. I don't know this is the right way but i am using the eosio.token contract's transfer function in my smart contract.

Comment: If you are using eosio.token to transfer via your contract, then you have to give correct permissions. follow this: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/whose-permission-is-required-while-sending-transaction-and-how-can-we-give-that

Comment: I understand but if random user want to transfer token on web app. For your reference so that you can have idea what i am trying to say : https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/how-to-send-eos-based-tokens-from-one-account-to-another?rq=1